# Elevation / pipeline Elevation calculation

Tags: civil-engineering, pipelines

We do inspections using a robotic camera in the pipeline. It’s tractor type camera. (Ref. photo)

[image: Pipeline Inspection camera]

[image: camera inspection video]

While driving the camera through the pipeline it gives us the camera tilt degree output.

The camera System gives us output as below,
[image: camera tilt output degree against mar]

**could please help me to calculate the elevation/altitude of each meter. Using camera tilt degree value**.

As below. 
[image: example elevation graph]

Awaiting for your answers. If you need any further info. Let me know.

Comment: You can convert "tilt" to gradient, and then use y=mx+c to calculate the X/Y coordinates of your next point based on that slope

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JonathanRSwift . Can you show me one example, how it’s calculated?

Comment: Just a visual ? No EMI or UT ? Seems inefficient.

Comment: @user268699 is **m** the total distance travelled, or the distance travelled since the last measurement?

Comment: @Andrew  distance traveled from the beginning of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the original starting position, you can use trigonometry to work out the profile of the pipeline.

If you take coordinates $(x_n,y_n)$, and with a measured 'inside pipe travel distance' of $d_n$ meters inside the pipe, down a slope of $\theta_n°$, then that coordinate can be caluclated:

$$x_n=x_{n-1}+\left(d_n-d_{n-1}\right)\sin\left(\theta_n\right)$$
$$y_n=y_{n-1}-\left(d_n-d_{n-1}\right)\cos\left(\theta_n\right)$$

It is important to note, that while the negative incline of the pipe is increasing, this approach will slightly over-estimate the altitude of each point, and slightly under-estimate as it is levelling out. Over a long run of pipe, this should even out, and the total change in altitude from end to end will be fairly accurate.

Here is an image of the graph that I was able to generate using the data that you supplied above:

[image: Graph generated from supplied data]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really appreciate it. I’ll discuss this one with our team.

Comment: Jonathan, could you please help me to solve one example equations for one degree value? I’m not familiar with this math. Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Jonathan could you please help me on this? I try to solve how you find the solution using that formula. Or can you send a soft copy of that graph to my email. (edwinvino@live.com)

Comment: You have a table of values for $d$ and $\theta$, which can be referred to sequentially as $d_1$, $d_2$ etc. $d_n$ is the term for any chosen value, and $d_{n-1}$ refers to the value of $d$ at the previous point. To calculate the X/Y coordinates of any point, simply use the formulas I have supplied above. N.B you need to know the X/Y coordinates of the first point.

Comment: Wetransfer link to the spreadsheet: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8ff09c9cafaa39129ba01d6bd730c76e20180508103922/8e3bed482bef938b77e0a1308f9e627f20180508103922/2609db